# How to change the aspect ratio of data frame in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layouts, data-frame

I want to be able to change the aspect ratio of data frame in layout view but it seems that there is no way to untick the related option in `Data Frame Properties` window!!!

[image]

I tried to use the following post on Esri's website to solve the problem but the icons in my **Production Cartography** toolbar are inactive.

**[Setting a data frame to allow the size to vary](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/allowing-data-frame-size-to-vary.htm)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the "Data Frame" tab of your data frame properties windows and change the setting from "Fixed extent" to either "fixed scale" or "automatic" (not sure of exact wording of option, I don't have an English version to check). The "Fixed extent" option set there has to lock the ratio as this is the only way to keep the extent fixed.

This should let you change the aspect ratio but you may still need to uncheck the preserve aspect ratio box on the "size and position" tab.